# Android intent как "Поделиться" двумя строками?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Я пытался сделать встроенный редактор JSON в своём Android приложении.
Одна из функций этого редактора - возможность отправить имя файла и его содержимое в любое приложение.
Мне нужно передать не как файл, а как текст, поскольку при передаче текста через [KDEconnect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=ru) на ПК открывается текстовый редактор с этим текстом.

Я написал следующий код:

```
public void shareFile(View view) {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(fileName.getText().toString() + "<br>" + fileContent.getText().toString()));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,getString(R.string.action_share)));
    }
```

У меня такой код выдаёт то, что ни одно приложение это не поддерживает:
[image: Результат работы кода (нет приложений)]

Я это побывал на эмуляторе, на котором есть программа отправки e-mail и SMS.
Почти любая программа e-mail и SMS может читать 2 строки...
После этого я взял код с сайта Android Developers. У меня получилось открыть приложение отправки SMS, но e-mail всё ещё не предлагает.

```
public void shareFile(View view) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, fileName.getText().toString() + "\n" + fileContent.getText().toString());
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    }
```

Почему это не работает?

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли, что приложение для отправки SMS может обрабатывать `text/html`? E-mail-клиент, да, обработает, и у меня на устройстве (Android 6) обрабатывает, однако в эмуляторе почему-то нет.

Comment: Всё верно. SMS не поддерживает HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустить этот код на телефоне (на эмуляторе работать не будет):

```
public void shareFile(View view) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, fileName.getText().toString() + "\n" + fileContent.getText().toString());
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
    }
```

HTML не подходит, поскольку его не принимают некоторые программы (например SMS)